# Loading a HTML snippet into a dynamically created iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to load a HTML snippet into a newly created iframe in the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iframeId = "frame"
            + Math.floor((Math.random() + "") * 1000000000000).toString();

    document.write('<iframe height="300"'
        + ' width="300"'
        + ' frameborder="0"'
        + ' scrolling="no"'
        + ' id="' + iframeId + '"'
        + ' name="' + iframeId + '"'
        + ' allowtransparency="true"></iframe>');

    var iframe = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    var iframeContent = '<!-- --\><script language=\"javascript\"\></script\>';
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();

    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(
        '<!DOCTYPE html\><html\><head\><title\>Test</title\></head\><body\>'
        + iframeContent
        + '</body\></html\>');

    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this document in a browser, the iframe is not loaded properly. Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

If I set iFrameContent as

```
var iframeContent = '<!-- --\>';
```

or

```
var iframeContent = '<script language=\"javascript\"\></script\>';
```

the page seems to load properly.

iframeContent is essentially a third party HTML snippet (escaped using freemarker js_string) and may contain HTML comments.

Comment: You don't need to call .toString() when concatenating.  Javascript does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the only way that the browser knows that your script section is done is to look for the "" tag, and you've got one of those right in the middle of your script.  It thinks that that is the end of your javascript, and so of course that's a syntax error.  It may also notice the "" tag, and think you have nested scripts.  You can try something like this:

```
var iframeContent = '<!-- --\><' + 
    'script language=\"javascript\"\></' + 'script\>';
```

And see if that works.

Even better is to use something like document.createElement or the jQuery library to create your DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that your code is working in IE, but not in other browsers. To get it work, you'll need somehow to escape token beginning a comment, for example:

```
var iframeContent = '<!\-- --\><script language=\"javascript\"\></script\>';
```

Ending `</script\>`-tag is not an issue here, because it's not literal `</script>` in the code.